# Count Fibonacci "cost" in scheme

Tags: scheme

I have to make a function that finds the "cost" of a Fibonacci number. My Fibonacci code is

```
(define fib (lambda (n) (cond
                      ((< n 0) 'Error)
                      ((= n 0) 0)
                      ((= n 1) 1)
                      (else (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))))
```

Each + or - that is used to evaluate a fib number is worth $1. Each < or > is worth $0.01. For example, 1 is worth $0.01, 2 is worth $3.03, etc. I don't know how to count the number of +, -, <, and >. Do I need the fib code in my fibCost code?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez My implementation also yields a cost of $3.03.

Comment: @uselpa you're right, it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty solution would be to define a `counter` variable each time the cost procedure is started, and update it with the corresponding value at each branch of the recursion. For example:

```
(define (fib-cost n)
  (let ((counter 0)) ; counter initialized with 0 at the beginning
    (let fib ((n n)) ; inner fibonacci procedure
      ; update counter with the corresponding cost
      (set! counter (+ counter 0.01))
      (when (> n 1)
        (set! counter (+ counter 3)))
      (cond ((< n 0) 'Error)
            ((= n 0) 0)
            ((= n 1) 1)
            (else (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))))))
    counter)) ; return the counter at the end
```

Answering your second question - no, we don't need the whole `fib` code; given that we're not interested in the actual value of fibonacci, the above can be further simplified to just make the required calls and ignore the returned values:

```
(define (fib-cost n)
  (let ((counter 0)) ; counter initialized with 0 at the beginning
    (let fib ((n n)) ; inner fibonacci procedure
      ; update counter with the corresponding cost
      (set! counter (+ counter 0.01))
      (when (> n 1)
        (fib (- n 1))
        (fib (- n 2))
        (set! counter (+ counter 3))))
    counter)) ; return the counter at the end
```

Comment: And this is why I don't use scheme.

Comment: @Mikhail What is the reason you don't use Scheme?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether or not you *wanted* the solution to include the original code or not.  There are direct ways of computing the cost, but I think it's interesting to look at ways that are similar to *instrumenting* the existing code.  That is, what can we *change* so that something very much like the original code will compute what we want?

First, we can replace the arithmetic operators with a bit of indirection. That is, instead of calling `(+ x y)`, you can call `(op + 100 x y)`, which increments the `total-cost` variable.

```
(define (fib n)
  (let* ((total-cost 0)
         (op (lambda (fn cost . args)
               (set! total-cost (+ total-cost cost))
               (apply fn args))))
    (let fib ((n n))
      (cond 
        ((op < 1 n 0) 'error)
        ((= n 0) 1)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        (else (op + 100
                  (fib (op - 100 n 1))
                  (fib (op - 100 n 2))))))
    total-cost))
```

That doesn't let us keep the original code, though.  We can do better by defining local versions of the arithmetic operators, and then using the original code:

```
(define (fib n)
  (let* ((total-cost 0)
         (op (lambda (fn cost)
               (lambda args
                 (set! total-cost (+ total-cost cost))
                 (apply fn args))))
         (< (op < 1))
         (+ (op + 100))
         (- (op - 100)))
    (let fib ((n n))
      (cond 
        ((< n 0) 'error)
        ((= n 0) 1)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        (else (+ (fib (- n 1))
                 (fib (- n 2))))))
    total-cost))
```

```
> (fib 1)
1
> (fib 2)
303
> (fib 3)
605
> (fib 4)
1209
```

What's nice about this approach is that if you start using macros to do some source code manipulation, you could actually use this as a sort of poor-man's profiler, or tracing system.  (I'd suggest sticking with the more robust tools provided by the implementation, of course, but there are times when a technique like this can be useful.)

Additionally, this doesn't even *have* to compute the Fibonnaci number anymore.  It's still computed because we do `(apply fn args)`, but if we remove that, then we never even call the original arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0):

You have +/- just anytime you call the code recursively, in the **else** Part. So, easily anytime you enter the else part, you should count 3 of them. One for **f(n-1)**, one for **f(n-2)** and one for **f(n-1) + f(n-2)**.

Comment: That helps a little, but how do you count how many times a recursion happens?

Comment: You can just set a counter in the **else** part, so anytime you call it, the counter will be increased by 3. 
If you need intuition about number of recursions, you can check the recursion tree of **fib** for an arbitrary number. Consider **n = 5**. **F(5)** is the root and it has two children [**F(3)**, **F(4)**]. Each one, respectively has [**F(1)**, **F(2)**] and [**F(2)**, **F(3)**] and so on.
Although, you can solve the **-Fibonacci-** problem using -Dynamic Programming- and it will be much more efficient, since it doesn't solve overlapping sub-problems again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a solution using syntactic extensions (aka "macros").

Let's define the following:

```
(define-syntax-rule (define-cost newf oldf thiscost totalcost)
  (define (newf . parms)
    (set! totalcost (+ totalcost thiscost))
    (apply oldf parms)))
```

Now we create procedures based on the original procedures you want to have a cost:

```
(define-cost +$ + 100 cost)
(define-cost -$ - 100 cost)
(define-cost <$ <   1 cost)
```

so using `+$` will do an addition and increase a cost counter by 1, and so on.

Now we adapt your inititial procedure to use the newly defined ones:

```
(define fib
  (lambda (n)
    (cond
      ((<$ n 0) 'Error)
      ((= n 0) 0)
      ((= n 1) 1)
      (else 
       (+$ (fib (-$ n 1)) (fib (-$ n 2)))))))
```

For convenience, we create a macro to return both the result of a procedure and its cost:

```
(define-syntax-rule (howmuch f . args)
  (begin
    (set! cost 0)
    (cons (apply f 'args) cost)))
```

then a cost variable

```
(define cost #f)
```

and off we go

```
> (howmuch fib 1)
'(1 . 1)
> (howmuch fib 2)
'(1 . 303)
> (howmuch fib 10)
'(55 . 26577)
> (howmuch fib 1)
'(1 . 1)
```